# How WebConfig appsetting value can be called inside a window.open function ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config, window.open

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='window.open("https://google.com")' />
```

I have to change this using webconfig appsettings.

In webconfig, I have

```
<add key="Google" value="https://google.com"/>
```

I have to get the url webconfig using the key.

I have tried

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='window.open("<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"] %>")' />
```

But it is not working.

Could you find a solution to access the webconfig appsettings values in window.open function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JS method:

```
function openUrl(url) {
  var newWind = window.open(url, '_blank');
  newWind.focus();
}
```

and:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='openUrl("<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"].ToString() %>")' />
```

Or read key in JS

```
function openUrl() {
      var url = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"].ToString() %>';
      var newWind = window.open(url, '_blank');
      newWind.focus();
 }
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks for the help. :) But near the double quotes is showing error message "unterminated string constant"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable in the code behind, for example

```
string openUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"];
```

And then in the page

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='window.open("<%= openUrl %>")' />
```

EDIT - based on the comment of wanting to do it in the aspx page itself (not sure why you would want to do this, but I'm sure you have your reasons).

```
<% string openUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]; %>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='window.open("<%= openUrl %>")' />
```

Comment: Is there any solution in aspx page itself?

Comment: I suppose you could wrap the variable declaration inside a code block with <% %> if you really want to go down that path. See my edit.